# Does JSON Schema have a switch like structure?

Tags: jsonschema

Consider this following example,

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "Animal",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Type of animal."
        },
        "data": {
            "$ref": "#/$definations/cat"
        }
    },
    "$definations":{
      "cat" : {
        "properties" : {
          "meow" : {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "required": ["type"]
}
```

and the correct JSON is ,

```
{
  "type" : "cat",
    "data" : {
      "meow" : "OK"
    }
}
```

Now I am having enum of Animals, and the data ref will vary based on type of Animal.

I have have tried `if else` but it seems not efficient as the condition will keep on growing.

Also used `anyOf` but how will I make sure that `meow` will always belong to animal type `cat` and not `dog`.

Can we have something like,

```
 cat : { "$ref" : "#/$definations/cat" },
  dog : { "$ref" : "#/$definations/dog" }
```

EDIT : Or dynamic value in ref like `#/$definations/{type-value}` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @Relequestual's response and some more digging I found there is no such way. At least in this version, fingers crossed for the future releases.

Here is my solution, feel free to suggest improvements.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Animal",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Type of animal."
    }
  },
  "$definations": {
    "cat": {
      "properties": {
        "meow": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "meow"
      ]
    },
    "dog": {
      "properties": {
        "bhow": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "bhow"
      ]
    }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "const": "cat"
        },
        "data": {
          "$ref": "#/$definations/cat"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "const": "dog"
        },
        "data": {
          "$ref": "#/$definations/dog"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "required": [
    "type"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have have tried `if` `else` but it seems not efficient as the condition
> will keep on growing.

> Can we have something like...

No. JSON Schema (2019-09 and previous) doesn't have a "switch".

You'll need to use `allOf` to create multiple `if` `then` conditions.

Comment: is it possible in the latest version? Can you give me any link ?

Comment: That is the current latest version. It will not be included in the 2020 version either. Essentially, no you cannot currently do this.

Comment: what about dynamic ref like `#definations/{type-value}` ?

Comment: The spec doesn't allow for such things.

Comment: Thanks for your response, guess I'll have to settle with `anyOne`

Comment: If you do that, make sure you `else: false` or you'll likely run into problems.